# Ubuntu Touch Phone Apps on Desktop

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I'm running Ubuntu Touch on a Galaxy Nexus. Loving it. Is there a way to run the phone-app on a desktop from the phone?

I.e., if we were running x11, I would simply export this through an ssh session. I've installed xorg (minimal X server), and can run X apps from my phone on my desktop. Is there a way to do the same with qml apps? Want to be able to send sms messages from my computer through the phone, and am looking for a quick and dirty hack to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I dont't think this is possible at the moment. But for a quick and dirty hack you could just ssh into your phone and then send sms using the cli:

```
/usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms /ril_0 <target phone number> "your Text" 0
```

If you have multiple sim cards installed:

```
ril_0
```

represents your first sim and

```
ril_1
```

represents the second sim.

But while Mir and Unity 8 are getting more and more mature, we might see a GUI that can do this in the future.